# what preposition should be used in front of "morning shift"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I wonder which preposition should be placed in front of "morning shift", in, on or at?
for example

> We plan to manufacture this order **on** tomorrow's morning shift.

Answer (score 0):

"On" is certainly used when referring to shifts.

> "Are you on morning or night shift this week?"
>
> "I *think* I'm on morning; I was on night last week though, so I wish they'd keep me on it."

Your context is slightly different, but I'd still tend to go for "on". Another option might be "during":

> "You lost your watch? And you've no idea when or where?"
>
> "Well...I'm pretty sure it was during the morning shift, just after we got started."